# Email Forwarding on Amazon Web Service SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I'm trying to set up an email to go to my custom domain name, which I will call "mydomainname". Currently I can send emails to "contact@mydomainname.com" and receive no error from sending the email, but the received email does not show up in my bucket or spam folder.

I've been following instructions on [this github](https://github.com/arithmetric/aws-lambda-ses-forwarder) and [this tutorial](http://www.daniloaz.com/en/use-gmail-with-your-own-domain-for-free-thanks-to-amazon-ses-lambda/) .

**I don't understand what the github instructions mean for the instruction that states**

*"Modify the values in the config object at the top of index.js to specify      the S3 bucket and object prefix for locating emails stored by SES. Also provide
the email forwarding mapping from original destinations to new destination."*

I've tried to guess at what that means by changing the index.js file to the as shown here [image]

I suspect there is an error in the code above,

As well, **I receive the following error for the JSON in my lambda-basic-execution**

[image]

And the error that I receive

[image]

.

.

.

I've included the following screenshots for reference

This is my recipient rule

[image]

This shows some information on the settings of my lambda page

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error you show is just a warning for the resource not existing, you should still be able to create the policy for the same. See if you actually did create the policy and test it again

Comment: @TarunLalwani  It turns out I had a duplicate rule by the same name, where the resource was being called S3bucketName, and my function was calling this duplicate rule instead. So I can receive emails sent to my domain now

Comment: Glad its solved, took the liberty of combining both our comments and post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you show is just a warning for the resource not existing, you should still be able to create the policy for the same.

See if you actually did create the policy and test it again.

Also make sure there are no invalid or duplicate rules which may be causing the issue